# API can't find my API key in header even though i included it

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to use the tequila API to retrieve flight prices but the server keeps returning this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Senna\Downloads\flight-deals-step-2-solution\flight-deals-step-2-solution\main.py", line 37, in <module>
    flight = flight_search.check_flights(
  File "C:\Users\Senna\Downloads\flight-deals-step-2-solution\flight-deals-step-2-solution\flight_search.py", line 54, in check_flights
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\Senna\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 953, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://tequila-api.kiwi.com/v2/search?fly_from=AMS&fly_to=CDG&date_from=15%2F08%2F2021&date_to=10%2F02%2F2022&nights_in_dst_from=7&nights_in_dst_to=28&flight_type=round&one_for_city=1&max_stopovers=0&curr=GBP
Process finished with exit code 1
```

this is my code:
(method in class)

```
    def check_flights(self, origin_city_code, destination_city_code, from_time, to_time):
        headers = {"apikey": TEQUILA_API_KEY}
        query = {
                "fly_from": origin_city_code,
                "fly_to": destination_city_code,
                "date_from": from_time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),
                "date_to": to_time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),
                "nights_in_dst_from": 7,
                "nights_in_dst_to": 28,
                "flight_type": "round",
                "one_for_city": 1,
                "max_stopovers": 0,
                "curr": "GBP"
            }

        response = requests.get(
                url="https://tequila-api.kiwi.com/v2/search",
                headers=headers,
                params=query,
            )
        response.raise_for_status()

        try:
                data = response.json()["data"][0]
        except IndexError:
                print(f"No flights found for {destination_city_code}.")
                return None

        flight_data = FlightData(
                price=data["price"],
                origin_city=data["route"][0]["cityFrom"],
                origin_airport=data["route"][0]["flyFrom"],
                destination_city=data["route"][0]["cityTo"],
                destination_airport=data["route"][0]["flyTo"],
                out_date=data["route"][0]["local_departure"].split("T")[0],
                return_date=data["route"][1]["local_departure"].split("T")[0]
            )
        print(f"{flight_data.destination_city}: £{flight_data.price}")
        return flight_data
```

Comment: Looking at [the documentation](https://tequila.kiwi.com/portal/docs/tequila_api/search_api), it seems as if the api key is meant to be provided as a parameter, not as a header.

Comment: i tried that but when i do that i get an HTTPS 400 error with a JSON payload that says: {"error_code":400,"message":"Use 'apikey' in header"} :/

Comment: so I ended up creating a new API- key and this "fixed" it somehow but still occasionally giving an error code but it sometimes works..

Answer (score 1):

you need to format the headers as a dictionnary like this:

```
HEADER = {'apikey': YOUR_API_KEY}
```

then you can request the data:

```
requests.get(url=API, headers=HEADER, params=params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Im also doing the course and got absolutely trainwrecked on the header not being recognized.
After 2 hours of trying every possible solution to make the header reach the API I recognized that I forgot to format date_to in the correct string format.
So despite the API is giving me header not found the issue was with one of my parameters.
So just give it another go and check your code character by character against the API documentation and I am sure you will find a tiny bit that has a typo or wrong format and your request will eventually go through.

Answer (score -1):

```
class FlightSearch:
    def __init__(self):
        self.code = {}

    def get_destination_code(self, city_name):
        location_endpoint = f"{TEQUILA_ENDPOINT}/locations/query"
        headers = {"apikey": TEQUILA_API_KEY}
        query = {"term": city_name, "location_types": "city"}
        response = requests.get(url=location_endpoint, headers=headers, params=query)
        results = response.json()["locations"]
        code = results[0]["code"]
        return code
```

I think this code missed an `__init__` under the `FlightSearch` class. After adding this line, it worked.